# AngularJS + CSS animations to trade out inspector panes

Tags: angularjs

Been struggling on how to tie angular with CSS animations... I'm sure I'm not getting something fundamental.

My goal is to have a list of search results. When you click one, a detail view will slide out from under the list. When you click another, the old detail view slides back, the details for the new one load, and then the detail view slides back in.

I don't have any code to show that even remotely works, but if anyone can point me at an example or offer some basic code, I would be extremely grateful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use ng-animate for animations.

ng-animate essentially adds CSS classes to elements automatically (often for a short time) during, for example, state transitions, during the population of an ng-repeat, etc.
You do not add the CSS classes to elements yourself this is done by ng-animate.

You do, however, apply the styling for those class in your style-sheet.
Its up to you, in your CSS, to do something with those automatically added CSS classes. Typically, you might want to do a fade in using CSS transitions.

For example ... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions
OR 
http://www.nganimate.org/

The ng-animate link details exactly which classes are added when. There are too many to mention here.

You might also want to use ng-fx

ng-fx github is here https://github.com/AngularClass/ng-fx

ng-fx requires ng-animate

ng-fx can be seen at work on its demo page - http://hendrixer.github.io/

This should get you going :)

Answer (score 0):

I would go with [ng-show](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow).

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('SomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  
  //this can be a service with a ngResource, an ajax call using $http... this is a baaaaasic dummy example.
  $scope.yourScopeFunction = function(){
    $scope.data = '';
    $scope.data = {};
    $scope.data.param1 = 'Hello';
    $scope.data.param2= 'Jhon';
  }
  
}]);
```

```html
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="SomeController">
    <div >
        <div class="elementClass" ng-click="yourScopeFunction()">Element1</div>
        <div class="elementClass" ng-click="yourScopeFunction2()">Element1</div>
    </div>
    <div  class="yourClass" ng-show="data != ''">
        <div>{{data.param1}}</div>
        <div>{{data.param2}}</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Then, when the **ng-show**'s expression evaluates to true (the *data* variable has some content), Angular will attach a new *class* to your **yourClass** element called
**.ng-hide-add** and when it evaluates to false, Angular will add the class **.ng-hide-remove**.

You just have to make the transition (or animation you want) based on the classes your element will have in both those moments. Like in the documentation example.

Something like:

```
.yourClass.ng-hide-add{
   //some transition or animation css
}
.yourClass.ng-hide-remove{
   //some transition or animation css
}
```

Note that my function on the example does a `$scope.data = '';` so the angular **ng-show** expression evaluates to false and the **.ng-hide-remove** is added.

By the way, you will need to add Angular Animations library.

Comment: This seems close, but I'm missing something. If my data variable is 1, and it changes to 2, I want to hide the panel while that data is loading.

Comment: You can put the angular expression you want inside the ng-show. Read about angular expressions. Explain better your case, or add some fiddle.